# Use daterange as key in Postgres for aggregated time series data

Tags: postgresql, data-modeling, data-warehouse

We are dealing with time series aggregated data, aggregated to a fixed type of period, e.g. weeks from Tuesday to Wednesday.

Would it be considered "bad practice" to use the Postgres `daterange` type as a `key` for this data? (Instead of e.g. having a `"PeriodID"`-key that defines this daterange and then join in a Calendar-dimension to identify that daterange.)

In my mind it would just be redundant with a separate `"PeriodID"` as a `daterange` has a very clear definition (and in our setting it will be unique to each observation).

Are there:

- Performance considerations?
- Other considerations?

Comment: I think it depend more on how you are going to qry it later. Usually you just create index on timestamp and compare it against ts. If you need range, you can just generate_series with 7 days period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an abstract level, a `tstzrange` would be the perfect representation for such an aggregation.

The problem that you should consider is how you would query the data, and how efficiently indexes can be used.

If you want to index the “contains” operator `@>` or the “overlaps” operator `&&`, you cannot use B-tree indexes, only GiST and SP-GiST indexes (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING)). You'd have to benchmark this, but odds are that using such an index would be slower that using a B-tree index on a `timestamptz` column. The index might also use more space.

A simple way to use `timestamptz` with a B-tree index would be to store the lower end of the range and query like this:

```
... WHERE weekstart <= atimestamp
      AND weekstart > atimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
```

Or to query for an overlapping interval:

```
... WHERE weekstart <= endtimestamp
      AND weekstart > starttimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
```